# Can't launch iOS Simulator from Visual Studio 2015 after Mac Update from 10.0 to 10.1

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2015

I am working in Visual Studio 2015 Community and developing a Xamarin.Forms app. I am connected to an iMac running and have successfully been launching the app on iOS Simulator for debugging. As of yesterday it stopped working and I get the the following info.

**Debug Log**:

> Launch failed. The app 'app-name-here' could not be launched on
>   'device-name-here'...

**Error Log**:

> Failed to launch the simulator: Could not load the framework
>   'libswiftos.dylib' (path:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftos.dylib): not
>   found. error MT1008: Failed to launch the simulator: Could not load
>   the framework 'libswiftos.dylib' (path:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftos.dylib): not
>   found.            0

I noticed that the iOS version shown on the simulator has been changed from 10.0 to 10.1 so it looks like the Mac installed an update.

I found some other posts that suggest maybe the file was moved or renamed in the latest Mac SDK and so Xamarin just needs to change where it's looking. Does that sound like the case here?

I've restarted the Mac and Visual studio.

On the Mac, I opened XCode and used Preferences\Components to install the iOS 10.0 Simulator so I could continue to debug on 10.0 devices, but still get the error so I don't think it's specific to the Simulator but rather to the SDK version. Is there a way to roll back the SDK from 10.0 to 10.1?

Comment: https://releases.xamarin.com/technical-bulletin-xcode-8-1-gm/